# We should be asked to choose a kind of syntax highlighting!

Tags: discussion, syntax-highlighting

I see a lot of posts with "code blocks" that does not need to be syntax highlighted. e.g. stack traces. I am suggesting that we should add an option when you create a code block using the `{}` button. You can choose things like Java, C#, C++, XML etc. Or just nothing at all.

Isn't that a good idea?

Comment: In practice I've not noticed this to be that much of a bother.  Could you point to an example where it looks exceptionally garish?

Comment: For me that feature looks more like a [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar). Highlighting special words with different colours make the text a little bit more readable but I do not think it has a great impact though.

Comment: Just use the `<!-- language: foo -->` hints. `none` is an option.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: `lang-foo`, don't forget the `lang-` prefix.

Comment: @Cerbrus: I didn't (except on `lang-none`, I guess), but tags need no prefix, and I think it's silly to type `lang-cpp` when you can just type `c++` instead.

Comment: I totally forgot about tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stack Overflow usually guesses what language is used in a post, based on (as far as I can tell) tags and syntax.

If you want something different, use the following HTML comment above your code block:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
```

The SO help center has [a section that explains this more in-depth](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting).

> You can use either [one of the supported prettify language codes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109), like lang-cpp or lang-sql, or you can specify a tag, and the syntax highlighting language associated with this tag will be used